# Compute an approximate power when lambda = 10

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, statistical-power

[image]

I wanna reconfirm, is this the right way to answer this question? I'm pretty confused. And if not, how?:

Answer: 
[image]

[image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check all of your numerical calculations, but your approach seems correct to me.  The only potential thing I would mention is that even though 11 is contained within your confidence interval, this is not necessarily evidence that your data comes from $\text{Poisson}(11)$ specifically.  The only thing we can say for certain is that we do not reject the null under $\alpha = .05$ - we cannot conclude that this sample is *not* from a $\text{Poisson}(11)$.